# Why was this on-topic question unilaterally closed and migrated by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, moderators

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1126219/revisions) on context-free and regular grammars was unilaterally closed as off-topic and migrated to [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37771/relaxation-of-the-null-production-restriction-in-regular-and-context-free-gramma) by one of the moderators; I should like to know why. We have a long history of answering questions in this area of mathematics — and it **is** mathematics — and we have a number of regulars who are competent to do so. We also have appropriate tags, two of which were used by the OP.

Comment: This seems like a prime example of something that could have been asked on the Mods' Office chatroom.

Comment: @Asaf: Quite possibly — had I been aware of its existence. On the other hand, had the question been closed and migrated for any reason other than request by the OP, this would have been very much the right place to discuss what would in that case have been a real problem.

Comment: I’d really like to know the reason for the downvotes; I can’t see anything particularly controversial about a request for information.

Comment: Brian, I agree that if there was a problem it would be worth discussing. But it is much better to come with evidence, than with speculations and what can possibly be understood as angry tone (I'm sure you weren't mad with rage when you posted this meta thread). If you had asked on the chatroom and you would have received an unsatisfactory answer, coming here saying "Look, this and that happened, and the moderators did it for this and that reason, and I think this is unacceptable", the case for the thread would have been much stronger. In any case, my remark was for the future, rather than now.

Comment: Your original title was inflammatory. You did not ask an honest question, you wrote a complaint.

Comment: @quid: I don’t agree. It certainly wasn’t intended to be. In fact, I simply lifted an existing title that was suggested by the system and modified it to avoid title collision. And before posting I rewrote the question to make it *not* a complaint. (Though had the answer been anything else, it would quickly have *become* a complaint.) In any case, an uncommented downvote on that basis is worthless: it does nothing to correct the perceived problem.

Comment: @Asaf: I offered no speculations. I simply explained why I found the action odd.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Before you asked about the down votes, I was going to comment on that. Down votes on meta are supposed to oppose a stance in the post, yet I see people down voting questions which take no sides whatsoever, which are quite simply questions. I can't understand this. And even if in some absolute sense quid right about the original title being inflammatory, I don't believe for one second that even half of the down voters went back to check the title and then decided to down vote.

Comment: Brian, that you did. I didn't vote on the post (up or down), but I did feel the tone of the post to be less asking and more accusatory. That's what I meant, and that's probably the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @Asaf: I’m perfectly willing to believe that it’s a reason for at least some of the downvotes. I flatly deny that I offered any speculation at all as to the reason for the action. Anyone who thinks that I did is reading into the post something that simply is not there.

Comment: You spent about two thirds of the post explaining why OP is on-topic here. Why?

Comment: @GitGud: 4 downvotes came before I edited the title, so it is more than half.  The other 2, I don't know whether they checked the revision history, and it seems pointless to speculate.  (For what it's worth, I upvoted after I edited the title.)

Comment: @Jonas: I didn't take a close look at the revision history. But I *completely* understand the downvotes that accompanied the original title. (I didn't vote at all on the question; although I did vote Daniel Fischer's answer. Up. I voted it up.)

Comment: Having explained my spontaneous impulse to dv, let me also explain what the "real problem" in this an other situations is. It appears you take as some quasi-default assumption that the moderators do something odd. Why did the actual scenario not occur to you? Or, if it did, why couldn't you assume it is likely this and move on? (After all there is not that much at stake here, some users question would have been moved from one on-topic site to a comparable other on-topic site where they even have an account. Really, even if it would have been done just so, what's the big issue.)

Comment: Or, what would be so wrong would a moderator decide to move a question that had not received *any* attention at all over ten hours, which is pretty long for this site, to another site were one can assume it might (and in fact did!) get more attention? (Possibly, it would not the best course of action, but is it really so bad that it would have  been a "real problem"?) Perhaps try to change your default for such cases to "likely there is some good reason for that moderator action." It could be more pleasant for everybody.

Comment: @qudi Perhaps, because there is a long history of abuse of unilateral / binding votes. But you've only been a member for less than one-third of the site's lifetime, so I don't blame you for not being aware of that.

Comment: Something that could have been a two-line exchange in chat got turned into a full blown argument on meta. Usual rhetoric about "unilateral mod actions". General presumption of moderators actively trying to harm the website. Getting tired of some people [described in this comment](https://i.imgur.com/jPxCTH4.png). Trying to push a rant-like question off the front page. All these reasons made me downvote. If a mod was held at gunpoint and forced to migrate a question, I should call the police, but I didn't immediately assume that this is what happened...

Comment: @BillDubuque even admitting this, for the sake of argument, it could be beneficial to try to turn the page. The moderator involved is only in service since some weeks and active on the site about as long as I, which is not a long time as you remarked. Why would one want to reproach them  actions done years ago by others.

Comment: @quid I don't disagree with that. Having been a mod, I am a bit sympathetic due to the learning curve, and to the innate difficulties involved in reaching fair compromises. Hopefully communication among mods is mich better now than in earlier times (that will go a long way towards quickly bringing the new mods up to speed).

Comment: *Why was this on-topic question unilaterally closed and migrated by a moderator ?* $$~$$ [Do you even have to ask ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nm6DO_7px1I&t=205) ;-$)$

Comment: I think people should take great care when something seems or feels inflammatory or accusatory, not to assume that it was intended as such.  This is especially important when it appears in writing without the benefit of intonation and visual cues, facial expression etc., to aid in our assessment.  Having said that, we can all benefit in writing on contentious matters to take care that such writings might also be misconstrued, and to take appropriate measures to soften them. It's a little tragedy when silly misunderstandings lead to greater things which are then difficult to disentangle.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The author of the question flagged and requested it be migrated to [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchamge.com).

Although such questions are also on topic here, if the author requests migration, and the question is also on-topic on the requested target, I see no reason not to oblige.

Comment: Fair enough. $\;,$

Comment: Dang, the potential for intrigue was enormous...

Comment: Kudos for your composure in the face of second-guessing. Hopefully there will be more benefit of the doubt in the future from this crowd (or at least better use of the moderator channel). Keep up the good work, Dan.

Comment: @rschwieb: No kudos for the unwarranted assumption that a request for information was actually second-guessing. You may not be aware of the fact that it is not uncommon for questions in that area to get comments suggesting — usually incorrectly — that they belong elsewhere. This seems to me quite adequate reason to enquire why one was migrated. As it happens, there was a perfectly good reason, and I indicated my entire satisfaction (‘Fair enough’) very promptly — $11$ minutes before I was even allowed to accept the answer, in fact.

Comment: Dear @BrianM.Scott: As you have seen in earlier comments, regardless of your intention, you were projecting the image of second guessing. Now you are projecting the image of one who came for a throw-down but upon getting an answer that can't be argued with, now has to backpedal and excuse oneself. In the future, it might be wise to use any of the the quieter alternatives to make "requests for information." Jumping straight to meta posting has the hallmarks of one who expects no good answer, or an answer one wants to dispute. I'm willing to take your previous comment at face value ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ... but still think Daniel deserves praise. Regards

Comment: way to go daniel.